# Objective C - Calculate the last host in a network

Tags: objective-c, networking

The user either choses A B or C.
A - 10.0.0.0 /8
B - 172.16.0.0 /16
C - 192.168.0.0 /24

Then they can drag a slider to choose how many bits they want for the network portion.

After they've done that, I want to calculate the last host on that network.

For simplicity, just subnet zero. So 10.0.0.0 /16 would still have 10.0.0.0 as network address and 10.0.0.1 as first host.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 2):

Invert the subnet mask, then flip the last bit and OR it with the network address.

```
network address: 10.0.0.0
subnet mask: 255.255.0.0

binary snm:   11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000
inverted:     00000000.00000000.11111111.11111111

flipped last bit: 00000000.00000000.11111111.11111110
binary net addr:  00001010.00000000.00000000.00000000
OR operation:     00001010.00000000.11111111.11111110

last host:        10.0.255.254
```

Comment: Good answer... it should be mentioned that the notion of a "last host" is only meaningful when answering "what is the IP range?"  It is often -- almost the rule -- the case that DHCP servers will only serve a sub-range of addresses, leaving the rest available for static usage.